# How to reflow Foundation 5 Abide validation on Turbolinks page:change with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, turbolinks, zurb-foundation-5

We're having trouble getting the Abide validation feature of Foundation 5 to work with turbolinks.

The foundation documentation suggests that we use:

```
$(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

However, I'm not sure how to trigger this when turbolinks changes the page.

From the turbolinks documentation, it looks like we can do the following:

```
$(document).on("page:change", fix_abide)
```

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

I'm not sure how to get the Foundation reflow to work with Turbolinks "page:change".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
# module.js.coffee

$ ->

  $(document).on("page:change", ->
    $(document).foundation('orbit', 'reflow')
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (and I think you do) then you could use the following gem. Put it in your Gemfile:

```
# Using Turbolinks with jQuery
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

You can use the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
});
```

as usual. It works like a charm for me. Simply put the reflow inside.

The advantage is the convenience, that you don't need to think about the *page change* event anymore. It does the work for you.